# Does JIRA work well with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, jira

I'm evaluating JIRA for my work. The offical documentation says that it only supports SQL Server 2005. The sales person told me explicitly that 2008 is NOT fully supported. But we would like to use 2008 since we are standardizing on it.

For JIRA users/admins, if you have deployed it with SQL Server 2008, have you encountered any issues?  Or have you heard of any potential problems with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[With v4, apparently](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-15575)

[And confirmed here](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=36087&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about JIRA, but if their salesperson explicitly told you that 2008 is not fully supported, then I would highlight that as a risk in my evaluation.  Since salespeople will generally try to push the limits of what they can say the product would do, to me that is a giant red-flag that they know there is something in 2008 that causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed. Please refer to our documentation:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+JIRA+to+SQL+Server+2008